How can I train an LLM on an SQL database using langchain? Is it safe to do so in terms of production?
I am working on a chatbot system that uses the OpenAI API for LLM and Langchain for the SQL agent. I have doubts regarding data safety. There are several cases where popular LLMs poorly handle sensitive data. Is there any proof that my sensitive data is safe with these LLMs?
i refer to several sources but do not get authentic answer.
